# Why is proxy.cgi not executing?

Tags: java, jsp, gis, openlayers

When i enter the url .."http:localhost:9999/my-app/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi" i got the script of proxy.cgi instead of openlayers.org.
I am using Glassfish 3.0.1 in port 9999 and Geoserver 2.1.1 in port 8080.
I am doing my project in Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

It is because your Glassfish app server is not configured to run CGI. Take a look on this resource: http://jfarcand.wordpress.com/2006/04/06/enabling-cgi-support-in-glassfish/

I hope it will help.

BTW, URL you mentioned `http:localhost:9999/my-app/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi` seems wrong: the 2 slashes after 'http:' are missing. It should be: http://localhost:9999/my-app/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi

Comment: Thanx for your answer.I had followed http://jfarcand.wordpress.com/2006/04/06/enabling-cgi-support-in-glassfish/ accordingly but it didn't work out.I have created cgi folder under Web-inf and put proxy.cgi under it.I had this http://localhost:9999/my-app/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi but still blank page appears.The Live HttpHeader shows this

Comment: GET /TravelPlanner-00/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9999
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:6.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0.2
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: JSESSIONID=61f3f041565ef7f10df44bfb04d3; JSESSIONID=608c2c61c7ff937b40b4108a3ed1; treeForm:tree-hi=treeForm:tree:configuration:httpService

Comment: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.0
Server: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.0.1
Content-Length: 0
Date: Wed, 02 Nov 2011 21:36:15 GMT